# fig.gca() vs. fig.add_subplot()

Tags: matplotlib

Most examples of object-oriented matplotlib get an Axis object with something like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)

ax1.plot(...... etc.
```

Which I've always found to be non-obvious, especially from a matlab-perspective.
I recently found that equivalent results can be obtained via

```
ax1 = fig1.gca()   # "GetCurrentAxis"
```

Which makes way more sense to me (possibly only due to prior Matlab use).
Why is *add_subplot()* with a confusing *111* argument chosen as the preferred way to get an axis object?  Is there any functional difference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`plt.gca` gets the current axes, creating one if needed.  It is only equivalent in the simplest 1 axes case.

The preferred way is to use [`plt.subplots`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots) (and the docs/examples are indeed lagging a bit, if you want to start contributing, updating the docs is a great place to start):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
```

or

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks!  I very much like this plt.subplots() method you show - I'm just surprised that, it being the 'preferred way', I've never seen it before.  Is it stated as the preferred way somewhere, or is each user to just decided which technique makes most sense to us?

Comment: Not sure exactly where it is in the docs, but this is my understanding of the consensus among the devs.

Comment: Now some years later, *most* of the MPL examples now use `plt.subplots()`, EXCEPT for the following: "Surface3d" (`gca`), "Multiple Subplots" (`subplot`), "streamplot" (`fig.add_subplots`), "Polar Plots" (`suplot`), XKCD (`fig.add_axes`).   From here: https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/introductory/sample_plots.html

Comment: Posted an Issue on Github for the documentation: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/17023#issuecomment-608947135

Answer (score 1):

To creat 3D instance, there are three ways:

```
plt.gca(projection='3d')

plt.subplot(projection='3d')

fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
```

Maybe the third way is more complex.

Comment: Don't forget that there is the fourth way (command) which is "subplots".